# XPATH compare strings with special chars

Tags: php, xpath, special-characters

I'm trying to compare the contents of elements using xpath. 
Sample code:

```
div[@ class = "name" and. = "'.$ data.'"]
```

Unfortunately, sometimes $data contains &quotes or other special characters.

example:

```
My school is a "super"
```

In this case, I can not compare content. What can I do with this?

Answer (score 1):

The other answers (up to know) all suffer from escaping too many characters (eg., `addslashes($string)` also escapes double quotes).

Anyway, PHP only supports XPath 1.0 which suffers from bad escaping capabilities. From XPath 2.0 on, one can escape the quotes used to declare the string by doubling them (eg., `'foo''bar'` will return `foo'bar`). In XPath 1.0, there is no way to do so.

---

One way to get out of this would be to ignore single quotes in both the input and search value by using

```
$string = str_replace("'", "", $data);
$xpath = "div[@class = 'name' and translate(., \"'\", '') = '$string']";
```

The `str_replace` line removes all single quotes from the search token, and the `translate` call within XPath removes all single quotes from the string to compared with.

Comment: Thank you for your help. 
In my case it was enough to use this fragemntu: 

`$string = str_replace ('"','', $data);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [htmlentities](http://php.net/htmlentities) or [html_entity_decod](http://php.net/html_entity_decode)e, the way it suits you better, I didn't understood if you have special characters, or they were in the data.

Check php documentation.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a function called "addSlashes" to fix this problem. It's use:

```
    addSlashes(your_php_variable);
```

Answer (score 0):

A function called `addslashes()` escapes special characters such as quotes.

Try this:

`div[@ class = "name" and. = "'.<?php echo addslashes($data) ?>.'"]`